# Need help formatting this to get insert query to work

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql

I am struggling very hard to try to figure out how to do this. I am trying to have inputs from textboxes allow the admin to update the data in Archive_Decade_Tbl and insert a row in the Archive_Image_Tbl if they chose to add photos. I have the update query working but I cannot for the life of me get the insert working. Be conscious that I am very new to this so my code will probably look disgusting to most of you and I am also not worried about security at the moment so I know that its vulnerable to SQL injection but please help me

Here is the code for the update function:

```
        protected void update_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e){

        string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("~\\database\\ARCHIVE_MASTER_DATABASE.accdb") + "; Persist Security Info=False;";
        DataSet infoDs = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter OleDbAdapter;
        classMe.Attributes.Add("class", "productInfoContainerNoFloat");
        string cmd1 = @"Select * From ARCHIVE_DECADE_TBL WHERE ARCHIVE_ID_NUMBER=@buttonClicked";
        string cmd2 = @"Select * From ARCHIVE_IMAGE_TBL WHERE ARCHIVE_ID_NUMBER=@buttonClicked";
        OleDbConnection dbConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
       try
    {
        dbConn.Open();
        OleDbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd1, dbConn);
        OleDbAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@buttonClicked", OleDbType.Integer).Value = archiveIdNumber.InnerText.Substring(33);
        OleDbAdapter.Fill(infoDs, "First Table");
        OleDbAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = cmd2;
        OleDbAdapter.Fill(infoDs, "Second Table");
        OleDbAdapter.Dispose();

        string cmdString = "Update ARCHIVE_DECADE_TBL Set PRODUCT_NAME='" + Request.Form["nameBox"] + "', MODEL_NUMBER='" + Request.Form["modelBox"] + "', YEAR_INTRODUCED='" + Request.Form["startBox"] + "', YEAR_DISCONTINUED='" + Request.Form["endBox"] + "', PRODUCT_LINE='" + Request.Form["lineBox"] + "', LOCATION='" + Request.Form["locationBox"] + "', QUANTITY='" + int.Parse(Request.Form["quantityBox"]) + "' " +
            "Where ARCHIVE_ID_NUMBER=" + int.Parse(Request.Form["archiveBox"]);

        OleDbAdapter.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand(cmdString, dbConn);
        OleDbAdapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dbConn.Close();
        if (addPhotos.HasFiles)
        {
            //cmdString = "Update ARCHIVE_DECADE_TBL Set PRODUCT_NAME='" + Request.Form["nameBox"] + "', MODEL_NUMBER='" + Request.Form["modelBox"] + "', YEAR_INTRODUCED='" + Request.Form["startBox"] + "', YEAR_DISCONTINUED='" + Request.Form["endBox"] + "', PRODUCT_LINE='" + Request.Form["lineBox"] + "', LOCATION='" + Request.Form["locationBox"] + "' " +
            //"Where ARCHIVE_ID_NUMBER=" + int.Parse(Request.Form["archiveBox"]);
            var x = 0;
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("includes/images/archives/" + Request.Form["archiveBox"] + "_1")))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("includes/images/archives/" + Request.Form["archiveBox"] + "_1"));
            }

            String filePath = Server.MapPath("includes/images/archives/" + Request.Form["archiveBox"] + "_1");
            HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;

            for (int i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile userPostedFile = uploadedFiles[i];
                if (userPostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    string extension = Path.GetExtension(userPostedFile.FileName);
                    //Request.Form["archiveBox"] + "_" + i will be the same as the "IMAGE" column in the IMAGE_TBL
                    uploadedFiles[i].SaveAs(filePath + "/" + Request.Form["archiveBox"] + "_" + (i + 1) + extension);

                }
                x++;
            }
            OleDbConnection dbConn2 = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            OleDbDataAdapter OleDbAdapter2;
            DataSet infoDs2 = new DataSet();
            try
            {
                dbConn2.Open();
                OleDbAdapter2 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd1, dbConn);

                string cmdString2 = "INSERT INTO ARCHIVE_IMAGE_TBL (ARCHIVE_ID_NUMBER, MODEL_NUMBER, LOCATION, IMAGE, NUMBER_OF_IMAGES, IMAGE_FILE_TYPE) VALUES ('" + Request.Form["archiveBox"].ToString() + "', '" + Request.Form["modelBox"].ToString() + "', '" + Request.Form["locationBox"].ToString() + "', '" + Request.Form["archiveBox"].ToString() + "_1" + "', '" + uploadedFiles.Count.ToString() + "', 'jpg');";
                testLbl.InnerText = cmdString2;
                OleDbAdapter2.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand(cmdString2, dbConn2);

                OleDbAdapter2.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

    }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Right now all I'm getting is that there is a syntax error in my Insert Into statement but I dont know why because I printed the string into a label, copy/pasted it into Access and it did exactly what I wanted

Comment: Can you give us the exact Syntax Error

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error is caused by the column named IMAGE. This is a reserved keyword for MS-Access and if you use it **in code** you need to encapsulate that name between square brackets.

So the start of your insert query should be written as

```
string cmdString2 = @"INSERT INTO ARCHIVE_IMAGE_TBL (ARCHIVE_ID_NUMBER, 
    MODEL_NUMBER, LOCATION, [IMAGE], NUMBER_OF_IMAGES, IMAGE_FILE_TYPE)  
    VALUES ( .......)";
```

Said that, please consider switching immediately to a parameterized query because, as is, you are just at the start of a sequence of possible syntax errors caused by implicit conversion and parsing problems. And Sql Injection hacks

So for example

```
string cmdString2 = @"INSERT INTO ARCHIVE_IMAGE_TBL (ARCHIVE_ID_NUMBER, 
    MODEL_NUMBER, LOCATION, [IMAGE], NUMBER_OF_IMAGES, IMAGE_FILE_TYPE)  
    VALUES (@id, @num, @loc, @img, @imgnum, 'jpg')";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdString2, con1);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = Request.Form["archiveBox"].ToString();
... and so on for the other parameters placeholders 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Remember to use the correct datatype for your parameters. If a columns expects an integer then create a parameter of `OleDbType.Integer` and set the value to an integer, the same for dates and floating point numbers.

By the way, to execute a command you don't need to have an OleDbDataAdapter.

Comment: Thank you so much. Those two little brackets made me want to jump in front of a train. I'll never use that as a column name again

Answer (score 0):

Do mean to be using `dbConn2` here, just above your insert statement?

```
...
dbConn2.Open();
OleDbAdapter2 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd1, dbConn);  // <-- here

string cmdString2 = "INSERT INTO ARCHIVE_IMAGE_TBL (ARCHIVE_ID_NUMBER, MODEL_NUMBER, LOCATION, IMAGE, NUMBER_OF_IMAGES, IMAGE_FILE_TYPE) VALUES ('" + Request.Form["archiveBox"].ToString() + "', '" + Request.Form["modelBox"].ToString() + "', '" + Request.Form["locationBox"].ToString() + "', '" + Request.Form["archiveBox"].ToString() + "_1" + "', '" + uploadedFiles.Count.ToString() + "', 'jpg');";
...
```

Also, I know you mentioned it, but please use parameters to eliminate the risk of SQL injection.  Also you want to dispose your disposable classes (connections, commands, etc.).